# Доработка стилей поиска по карте (searchControl)

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Здравствуйте!

**Кейс:**

Решил немного переделать поиск по яндекс-картам (элемент searchControl). 
Убрал отображение поисковой выдачи, включил поисковые подсказки и настроил переход на наиболее вероятный результат при клике по поисковой подсказке.
Единственный минус -- такая настройка не предполагает предупреждения пользователя в том случае, если ничего найдено не было.
Было решено поменять обводку у поля ввода на красную в том случае, если массив найденных результатов окажется пустым.

**Вопрос:**

Как это сделать наименее костыльным и наболее простым способом?

Меня полностью устраивает нативная верстка инпута, мне не хватает только одного стиля (красной обводки). Создавать отдельный макет поиска для такой мелочи, как мне кажется, -- стрелять из пушки по воробьям.

Сейчас я просто обратился к элементу из js по селектору, который подсмотрел в инспекторе. Такой способ работает, он довольно простой, но ненадежный, т.к. при смене версии яндекса все стили посыпятся, а из js обратиться к текущей версии я не могу.

Пример моего решения в песочнице:
http://jsbin.com/biqihiq

**ЗАРАНЕЕ СПАСИБО!**

Comment: нативная верстка инпута© вам нужно подсветить инпут?? https://stackoverflow.com/q/5670879/

Answer (score 1):

если проблема в выборе элемента инпут без класса то есть другой способ:

### раз

сделать свою обёртку, например в виде `div`, и искать в ней инпут

```js
var mydiv = mydiv || document.getElementById('mydiv')

let nodearr = mydiv.getElementsByTagName('input')

let inp = null

if (1 === nodearr.length) {
  inp = nodearr[0]
} else if (0 === nodearr.length) {
  console.error('ваще ничё не найдено')
} else {
  console.error('откуда блин второй?')
}

if(inp)inp.style.border = 'solid 3px red'
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <div>
    <input id="any" value="qwa" />
  </div>
</div>
```

### два

если есть функция обработчик вроде `qqf.addEventListener('input',(_e)=>{})`
то обратиться к инпуту можно вот так `_e.srcElement`
_e - Event

```js
var qqf = qqf || document.getElementById('qqf')
qqf.addEventListener('input',_e=>{
  _e.srcElement.style.border = 'solid 3px red'
  console.log(_e.srcElement.value)
})
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <input id="qqf" value="qwa" />
  </div>
</div>
```

### три

а с чего это яндекс должен обновиться?
вот я вижу тут

> `https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.62/map.js?callback=ym_map_fallback_url=https___api-maps_yandex_ru_2_1_62_map_js_filter=*&filter=*`

что используется апи версии `2.1.62` и если яндекс "обновится", то появится новая ссылка вроде `https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.2/` вы же тем временем будете и дальше работать с `https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.62/`

Comment: Спасибо за оперативный ответ! Я знаю, как подсветить инпут, я уже сделал это в примере в песочнице. Вопрос стоит в том, как сделать это максимально правильно с точки зрения архитектуры карт. Поэтому первый способ не подходит, т.к. требует правки верстки, к которой у меня доступа нет (она генерируется скриптом автоматически).

Comment: Попробовал второй способ: получил ссылку на оригинальный event, через кучу служебных свойств добрался до контейнера с контроллерами карты и через querySelector достал оттуда нужный инпут. Команда стала выглядеть так:

e.get('target')._layout._element.parentElement.querySelector('input');

Этот способ уже лучше, т.к. при смене версии скорее всего ничего не сломается, но минус в том, что он костыльный (приходится лезть в служебные свойства), не будет работать, если в элементах управления будут еще инпуты и может посыпаться, если создатели решат поменять верстку.

Comment: По третьему пункту: в песочнице скрипт подключается по этой ссылке: https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU. Патч версия здесь (третья цифра) не указана. В встроенной разметке в имени класса патч версия указана, поэтому стили отваливаются при обновлении

Comment: к стати, а если этот вопрос задать в самом яндексе?? неужто нет службы поддержки

Comment: вариант 3 использовать не стоит, во-первых, это может сломать стили API, во-вторых, минорная версия API регулярно обновляется и со временем такой код будет ломаться из-за выхода новых версий